# Async method call on ComboBox selection with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, async-await

I'm facing a problem with displaying graphs filtered by `ComboBox` selection without having the UI lock up. The statistic filtering is quite heavy and needs to run `async`. This works fine all up until I try to call `FilterStatisticsAsync` and `MonthSelectionChanged` from the Property setter. Does anyone have a good tip on how to solve or work around this?

The XAML looks like this:

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbMonth"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Months}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonth }"
                  IsEditable="True"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
```

And the ViewModel property setter like this:

```
    public string SelectedMonth
    {
        get { return _selectedMonth; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedMonth, value); LoadStatisticsAsync(); MonthSelectionChanged(); }
    }
```

`SetProperty` derives from a base class which encapsulates INPC like this:

```
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(member, value))
                return;

            member = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

Comment: Create an event handler and raise that on value changes. in the handler you can use async without blocking UI thread

Comment: Just adding to Nkosi's answer, create an async event handler that returns void and calls the desired method

Comment: Have you tried using `IsAsync=True` in your ItemsSource binding (and other long running propertiy call) and make your ComboBox use virtualization ? Make sure you raise every PropertyChanged in the main UI dispatcher or it might break.

Comment: It is interesting that you have a UI block problem at all. If LoadStatisticsAsync is truly async as the name suggests, UI should NOT block. Assuming MonthSelectionChanged and all its handlers are not doing weird staff, something is not right here. Try to identify the true cause of UI block first.

Comment: Embarassingly enough, Xiaoguo had the right answer. Having gone over the code I found a block in  LoadStatisticsAsync. Thanks for some great input.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using this:

```
    public class AsyncProperty<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public async Task UpdateAsync(Task<T> updateAction)
        {
            LastException = null;
            IsUpdating = true;

            try
            {
                Value = await updateAction.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LastException = e;
                Value = default(T);
            }

            IsUpdating = false;
        }

        private T _value;

        public T Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _value)) return;
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool _isUpdating;

        public bool IsUpdating
        {
            get { return _isUpdating; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _isUpdating) return;
                _isUpdating = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private Exception _lastException;

        public Exception LastException
        {
            get { return _lastException; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _lastException)) return;
                _lastException = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Definition of property

```
 public AsyncProperty<string> SelectedMonth { get; } = new AsyncProperty<string>();
```

somewhere else in your code:

```
SelectedMonth.UpdateAsync(Task.Run(() => whateveryourbackground work is));
```

binding in xaml:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonth.Value }"
```

Note that properties should reflect a current state, instead of triggering processes which may take an indefinite amount of time. Hence the need to update the property in a different way from just assigning it.